# TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int' getting a type error when comparing two integers

Tags: python, comparison

```
def calculate_years(principal, interest, tax, desired):
    firstYearProfit = principal*interest - principal*interest*tax
    years = 0
    profit = 0
    def calculateProfit(profit):
         profit = profit*interest - profit*interest*tax
    while profit <= desired:
        if years <= 0:
            profit = calculateProfit(firstYearProfit)
        else:
            calculateProfit(profit)
    return Profit
```

> The error is on line 6 the years <= 0: TypeError: '<=' not supported
> between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

I don't understand how `0` is of `NoneType`

Comment: Where is `desired`  defined?

Comment: there's some indentation problem here.. or probably the return at the end is not needed. It also returns a not declared variable.

Comment: `calculateProfit()` does not have a `return` statement, therefore it returns `None` by default.  So `profit = calculateProfit(firstYearProfit)` will always be None.

Comment: Change `profit =` to `return` in the function definition.

Comment: You also should make `interest` and `tax` parameters of the function, rather than using global variables.